# Allow Azure Web App to Access Database on the VM Without Exposing that VM to the World

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We have Web Apps that need to access database hosted on VM. What options exist that will allow Web Apps to access the databases without opening the database VM port to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, you can [integrate with the VNet for the Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet), it can make your Web App access the resources in the VNet. The VM that hosts the database can be created in the VNet without public IP address so that the VM can only be accessible in the VNet. Here is the description that can help understand it:

> VNet Integration gives your app access to resources in your VNet, but
>   it doesn't grant inbound private access to your app from the VNet.

Comment: Is it possible to allow Web Apps through NSG instead?

Comment: @WinBoss Of course Yes. You can use the NSG to allow or deny the traffic from the Web App. It also shows that in the link that I provided in the answer.

Comment: I don't see that in a linked document. I see "An app that uses regional VNet Integration can use a network security group to block outbound traffic to resources in your VNet or the internet."
I have verified that your suggest scenario works: when VM has no public IP and Web App has Virtual Network Integration enabled on a different subnet in the same vNet. But what NSG rule would I need to apply to VM that has NSG associated to it's Public IP to allow connections from different subnet?

Comment: @WinBoss What do you mean the VM with public IP? Don't you want the VM without public IP?

Comment: I'd like to have a VM with Public IP that would block all ports except 3389 coming from public internet and would block all ports except 1433 coming from another subnet (which would be associated to Web App virtual network integration).

Comment: @WinBoss Just create the inbound rules to allow or deny the source ports.

Comment: But how can I specify that I want to open port 3389 for connections from internet and 1433 for connections from subnet?

Comment: @WinBoss Associate the NSG to the subnet, create the rule to allow the port 1433 and 3389, and create a rule to deny all ports. But the priority of the allow rules should be smaller than the deny rule. This is a priority problem.

Comment: @WinBoss Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.